# Padding in p-tag for semi-transparent image-overlay

Tags: html, css

I have an `img` inside a `div` where I need to overlay a text-block that needs a padding.

The outer div-tag has overflow:hidden because the image needs to be cropped to a max-height.

If you look at my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Py49n/1/

you'll see that the text inside the p-tag gets written to far to the right, because the p-tag has a width of 100% + padding.

How can I achieve a margin on the text without making the p-tag wider?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box` (and appropriate prefixes) to allow the box to be sized to include padding. More info on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). Browser support is [pretty good](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing). If you need to support IE7, you'll need another solution, perhaps a polyfill.